# A node cannot exists twice in the state tree ( mobx-state-tree )

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm getting an error that says `Error: [mobx-state-tree] A node cannot exists twice in the state tree. Failed to add SearchModel@/results/0 to path '/selectedItem'` when assigning a value to `selectedItem` in the following model via the `setSelectedItem` action. I've checked the documentation and I'm not sure what's causing this issue.

Appreciate any help. thanks!

```
const SearchModel = types
  .model({
    results: types.array(ItemModel, []),
    selectedItem:types.maybeNull(ItemModel,{ id: 0 })
  })
  .actions(self => ({   
    setSelectedItem(selItem) {
      console.log( 'typeof(selItem)', typeof(selItem));
      self.selectedItem=selItem;
    }
  }));

export default SearchModel;
```

Comment: Instead of `maybeNull`, try to use a [`reference`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#references-and-identifiers) instead: `types.reference(ItemModel)`. One of the model fields in `ItemModel` also need to be an [`identifier`](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree#identifiers).

Comment: Try is not a correct word here - you should use `reference` in such case. Because `A node cannot exist twice in the state tree.`

Comment: thanks @Tholle and @jayarjo. I wasn't looking for a reference to the original object, I just needed a shallow copy. I've used the spread operator to assign a shallow copy of `selItem` to `self.selectedItem` and the issue went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to this type of an error in future, I've used the spread operator to assign a shallow copy of `selItem` to `self.selectedItem` and the problem went away.

The code had to look as follows:

```
const SearchModel = types
  .model({
    results: types.array(ItemModel, []),
    selectedItem:types.maybeNull(ItemModel,{ id: 0 })
  })
  .actions(self => ({   
    setSelectedItem(selItem) {
      self.selectedItem = { ...selItem };
    }
  }));

export default SearchModel;
```

Comment: This does not work if the ItemModel embeds another model

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use _.deepCopy, from the Lodash library. It's more versatile than the spread operator, since it will recursively go down an entire tree, instead of one level. That's useful for larger trees, so you don't have to double or triple or quadruple spread, and have hard-to-read code.

This is how you'd use it with a simple mobx-state-tree store. It's very elegant, easy to use.

Be advised: this is a recursive pass-by-copy function, so performance may be poor if an object is too large.

```html
import _ from 'lodash';
import { types, getRoot, destroy, flow } from "mobx-state-tree";
            
const SearchModel = types
  .model({
    results: types.array(ItemModel, []),
    selectedItem:types.maybeNull(ItemModel,{ id: 0 })
  })
  .actions(self => ({   
    setSelectedItem(selItem) {
      self.selectedItem = _.deepCopy(selItem);
    }
  }));

export default SearchModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue in our ***React TypeScript*** also our ***MST store*** was very nested and complex so using the spread operator or applySnapshot didn't work. By using [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) simply solved the issue.

**STEPS:**

*install:*  `npm i lodash.clonedeep`

*import:*   `import cloneDeep from 'lodash/cloneDeep'`

*Use it(In my case):* `self.filteredCashGamesList.cashGameTableView = cloneDeep(self.cashGameTableView)`

Answer (score 0):

One better possibility: use the mobx-state-tree applySnapshot function. This should auto-reconcile the data structures, and also preserves back/forth abilities, so you can take advantage of undo/redo for your state tree.

```js
import { types, getRoot, destroy, flow, applySnapshot } from "mobx-state-tree";
            
const SearchModel = types
  .model({
    results: types.array(ItemModel, []),
    selectedItem:types.maybeNull(ItemModel,{ id: 0 })
  })
  .actions(self => ({   
    setSelectedItem(selItem) {
      applySnapshot(self.selectedItem, selItem);
    }
  }));

export default SearchModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a nested object "address" on level 2, so I needed to specify the fix for it as well:

```
setSelectedItem(selItem) {
  let item = { ...selItem };
  item.address = { ...selItem.address }
  self.selectedItem = item;
}
```